# Explanation to Euler's Method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method

I am trying to figure out Euler's method.

The initial value problem is :
$$P'(t)=0.7P(t)(1-\frac{P(t)}{750})-20,  P(0)=30$$

The time step is set to $Δt=7$ days

For the algorithm we have:

$f(t,P)=0.7P(1-\frac{P}{750})-20$

$h=7$

$t_0=0$

$w_0=P(t_0)=P(0)=30$.

Could someone explain the next step? I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's method reads in this case
$$
P_0 = 30, \quad P_{i+1} = P_i + h \left( 0.7 P_i \left(1- \frac{P_i}{750}\right) -20\right)
$$

So, in your example,
$$
P(7)\approx P_0 + 7 \left(0.7 P_0 \left(1- \frac{P_0}{750}\right) -20\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks. You made it clear